# Can an F# abstract class type member expression be "abstract override"?

Tags: f#

You can declare a method `abstract override` in a C# abstract class.  You might do this to force a derived type to provide an implementation of a base method of `System.Object`, like `ToString()`.  It looks like this in C#:

```cs
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract override string ToString();
}
```

Is this possible in F#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The F# specification says the following about abstract members:

> An abstract member definition has the form:
>
> abstract *access<sub>opt</sub>* *member-sig*

Therefore, it appears not to be possible.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there is an F# equivalent to `abstract override`.  You could so something like this to get the same behavior:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type Base() =
    abstract GetString: unit -> string
    override this.ToString() = this.GetString()
```

Then you'd just override `GetString` in your derived types.

Comment: Thanks Aaron.  I am aware of the approach in your suggestion.  However, I'm looking to determine if the approach in my question is possible in F#.  I suspect not!